# JQuery - Method equals to c# All()-method

Tags: jquery

If I use c#, I do this below, to check if any element in a list equals a objects propery value, and if it does, don't add it to the list.

Is there any equal way of doing this with JQuery?

c#

```
public class Users
{
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
private static List<Users> userList = new List<Users>();
```

.

```
string currentUser = Context.User.Identity.Name;

if (userList.All(o => o.User != currentUser))
{
    userList.Add(new Users{ User = currentUser });
}
```

JQuery. Attempt...

I'm trying to add items to a list. If the item already is in the list, then don't add it. With my poor atempt it never gets added...

```
    //users is a list of objects with a property called User(usernames)
    //currentUserName is a string
    function onUserList(users, currentUserName) {

    var currentUser = currentUserName;

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].User != currentUser) {
            $("#monitorMgs").append('<li>' + users[i].User + '</li>');
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: You're using the wrong data structure.  You should be using a set here, rather than an indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple to do using jQuery each to iterate over your users array

```
function onUserList(users, currentUserName) {
    $.each(users, function() {
        if ($(this).User != currentUserName) {
            $('#monitorMgs').append('<li>' + $(this).User + '</li>');
        }
    })
}
```

Edit: As pointed out by TrueBlueAussie, you should actually use $.each(). I've rewritten my sample as such

Comment: Did you mean to use `jQuery.each( array, callback )`?